# How many downvotes are required to delete a question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[One of my questions](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47471/this-is-one-of-my-best-what-am-i) was deleted. Although it had many downvotes, the question was not bad and was also ORIGINAL.

If downvotes are only the count for "delete", why are other questions with more downvotes not deleted?

Also I feel many copied puzzles get upvoted, but my riddle was downvoted because a few people *motivated others to downvote* the question by putting diverting comments which were not required.

Comment: @Emrakul what wrong I did , due to which question was deleted?

Comment: If it had that many downvotes I think it is considered 'bad'

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil  few diverting comments to downvote , motivated many people to downvote..I feel the riddle is atleast much better than few copied puzzle ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is my view and may differ from rest**

> How many downvotes are required to delete a question?

[*For questions, a post that no longer adds anything to the site should be deleted.*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/339983)

So, it doesn't actually depend on number of down-votes but most often it depends on the content.

### 1. Copied puzzles get upvoted?

Yes they do. But only by the people who didn't knew if it was copied. If majority of people think, its copied, it's either closed or deleted as plagiarism.

### 2. My riddle was down voted because few people motivated others to downvote the question by putting diverting comments which were not required?

I didn't down voted at first, due to the fact that I was not sure if it was within the rules or not. But, majority of downvotes increased when you started editing the question with words like **"AD"** and it grew when you added another bounty to it asking for downvotes which I felt was sad.

### Advice

Move on. You have been a good contributor to the site. Mistakes happen. Don't stick to this one and keep making better puzzles in future.

*All the best!*

Answer (score 6):

It tingled my mod sense as a question that would be better deleted for a number of small reasons.

- It's score was... fairly low. While not a deciding factor, it certainly favors deletion.
- The presence of, and potential for further, vitriolic comments. Both to protect and prevent from future comments, and to make out of sight comments that have really already made their point.
- It's an ad for another puzzle. I briefly considered spam flagging it, but that would have been way too harsh and inappropriate. This, in particular, is what I meant when I wrote "please don't do this." (Sorry for the unclear comment!)
- Calling non-Puzzling users "losers" rubbed me the wrong way.
- I hate to be blunt, but it was a fairlyly low-effort riddle. It falls in with a lot of other riddles in the form of: pick an object, describe it in four ways, post a "what am I?" riddle. These usually don't take long to write, aren't very difficult, and are only very, *very* rarely interesting.

I wouldn't say there was a specific reason it was removed, but this all added up to a general feeling that it would be better - both for the site *and* you - if it were removed. It was getting an anomalous amount of negative attention, and by that point, a critique had already been demonstrated. Anything more would have just added salt.

I don't mean to discourage you from writing puzzles, though. I hope you find more success with puzzles in the vein of the well-received ones you've already posted.

Comment: (I moved this from a +3 comment to an answer, and expanded a bit upon it, based on a suggestion that it works better here.)